# Configuring IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate to add JAR to Classpath instead of Native location

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, classpath, native

I'm having a problem setting up my project libraries as expected in IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4 Ultimate. In my engine, I usually store the native libraries in the JAR and at runtime, extract them to a temporary directory and load them from there.

But IntelliJ Ultimate is detecting the JAR containing the natives as a Natives Library Location, when I wanted it to be on the classpath.

[image: What I get]

The problem is, I can't extract them at runtime since they are now not in the classpath, as said in the documentation of IntelliJ. However, the Community Edition is asking for how to add this JAR and I can select classes there.

[image: What is expected]

Is there any way to change that behaviour? I mean, add it to the classpath instead of the `java.library.path` property?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it really work as you'd expect in Community?  Do you want the *contents* of the `-native` jar file to be on the classpath, or do you want the jar file itself to be on the classpath?  I would have expected the Community approach to give you the former, when you want the latter.

Comment: Yes @MarkPeters, I'm storing the natives required by the LWJGL in the `lwjgl-natives.jar` file, and extract them to a temp directory at runtime. However when that is recognised as native location, they are no more in the classpath, so I can't extract the dll's inside that JAR at runtime.

Comment: Yes I need the contents of the native jar file in the classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have my copy of Ultimate available currently, so I'm not sure about solving this in the UI.

But one workaround would be to just edit the library config file directly.  If you're using the directory-based project format, it'll be in `.idea/libraries/MyLibrary.xml`.  Find your entry under `NATIVES` (or whatever it's called) and move it under `CLASSES` instead.

```
<component name="libraryTable">
  <library name="MyLibrary">
    <CLASSES>
      <root url="jar://$PROJECT_DIR$/lib/some-classes.jar!/" />
    </CLASSES>
    <JAVADOC />
    <SOURCES>
      <root url="jar://$PROJECT_DIR$/lib/some-classes-sources.jar!/" />
    </SOURCES>
  </library>
</component>
```

Be sure to close your project before making this change.

Comment: Thanks this worked. However I think I will wait for sometime before accepting, as I find this a little inconvenient. A GUI based option will be good.